# How to abstract the spinner in MAUI Blazor

Tags: blazor, maui-blazor

I would like to define a single place for the spinner.
I know that blazor will sometimes render the page/component before the OnInitializeAsync has finished running so the data might be null.

Now, I can put the logic to display the spinner while the data is null in every page/component, but would like a more elegant way of doing so, like some PageBase or ComponentBase.

How to do this in Blazor?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a component called `spinner` and put it in the /page/share. Now, you can call the spinner in any components when you need it.

Comment: But this requires custom logic in every component that handles the Spinner.show or hide! I want to automatize this. Ie when I make a call to any api I want to show the spinner. Ie by putting spinner in the MainLayout and showing it whenever i make an api call.

Comment: hmmm. So you can put the spinner component in the _layout and use cascading parameter to determine when the spinner show or hide. You can use the observer pattern too. https://remibou.github.io/Implementing-observer-pattern-in-Blazor/

Comment: Yes, this could work. Can You please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the spinner component in the _layout and use cascading parameter to determine when the spinner show or hide.

You can use the observer pattern too. For more info, you can refer to [Implementing Observer Pattern In Blazor](https://remibou.github.io/Implementing-observer-pattern-in-Blazor)